# Automapper with VS2010 is it AutoMapper (Verbatim)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, automapper

I am using VS 2010 and there is a project, I looked the properties and it says its .Net Framework 4 project. I like to add AutoMapper to this project for mapping objects. I tried VS2010 nugget Package Manager for search. and it showed AutoMapper(Verbatim) I like to know is this the one that is known as automapper with documentation given here https://automapper.org/

Thanks

Comment: You can update to VS2017 Community for free, btw.

Comment: No, but there is an older version of AM that supports .Net 4. Try [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/6.2.2 is the last to support .NET 4.